# Overwrite text file vs append

Tags: qt, qfile

I'm looking to overwrite data in a text file but all I can seem to do is append to it

```
mFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite)

QTextStream in(&mFile);
QString first = in.readLine(); //discard the headers
QString dataLine = in.readLine(); //headers
QStringList sql_row = dataLine.split("\t"); //first row (sake of proj only 1 row)

if(sql_row[1].isEmpty()) //no user name registered
{
    QByteArray user= getenv("USERNAME"); //for windows
    if(user.isEmpty())
        {
                user = getenv("USER"); ///for MAc or Linux
            }
    dataLine = dataLine.insert(dataLine.indexOf("\t")+ 1,user);

    in << first << endl << dataLine << endl;
    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change

```
mFile.open(QFile::ReadWrite);
```

to

```
mFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text);
```

The QIODevice vs QFile distinction isn't necessary, but I personally favor using the base class. The `Truncate` flag will overwrite (i.e., delete) an existing file.

Alternatively, you can follow the [other suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314370/1666676) and open your text file directly using one of QTextStream's constructors. The same [`QIODevice::OpenMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum) conventions apply. This only works if `mFile` is a `FILE` object and not a `QFile`, which isn't the case in your example.

---

A couple additional notes for beginners.

**Related Note 1**

You didn't ask about this, but I also added the `QIODevice::Text` flag to ensure that newline characters get translated to/from the local encoding (plain `\n` vs. `\r\n`) when you use [`endl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#endl).

A really common mistake is to use `\r\n` AND `QIODevice::Text`, which results in text files with double-returns `\r\r\n` on Windows. Just use `QIODevice::Text` when opening and simply `\n` or `endl` and you'll never have this problem.

**Related Note 2**

Using [QTextStream::endl](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#endl) will automatically call `flush()` each time. If your loop is large, use `"\n"` instead to prevent a slowdown unless you actually need to flush every line. The stream will automatically write to disk as its buffer gets full, or when it's closed.

[QFile::close()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledevice.html#close) also calls `flush()`, which makes your `mFile.flush()` at the end redundant.

Answer (score 10):

Use an overloaded constructor of QTextStream:

```
QTextStream in(&mFile, QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate);
```

The `QIODevice::Truncate` will remove all the previous content of the file, and `QIODevice::ReadWrite` will open it for read and write access.